# Java regex validating \[]

Tags: java, regex

My issues is to allow only `a-z, A-Z, 0-9`, points, dashes and underscores and [] for a given string.

Here is my code but not working so far.

`[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*` this one works ok for validating `a-z, A-Z, 0-9` points, dashes and underscores and but when it comes to add and [] i got error Illegal character. 
`[a-zA-Z0-9._-\\[]]`*
it's obviously that [] broke the regex.

Any suggestion how to handle this proble?

```
String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-\\[]]*";
String username = "dsfsdf_12";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(username);

if (matcher.matches()) {
   System.out.println("matched");
} else {
  System.out.println("NOT matched");
}
```

Comment: You need to escape `[` and `]` separately like this: `"[a-zA-Z0-9._-\\[\\]]*"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape both [] as shown below:

```
    "[a-zA-Z0-9._-\\[\\]]*"
```

Comment: Also i want to add as allowed char /, so i tried REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\\[\\\]]*"; with string str = "dsf\\sdf_[12]"; but it did not match it

Comment: the reason is that the backslash is not part of your regex, use "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\[\\]\\\\]*", or do you mean forward slash?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape both brackets, not just the left bracket:

```
String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-\\[\\]]*";
String username = "dsfsdf_12";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(username);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("matched");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NOT matched");
    }
```

String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\-\[\]\\]*";
The four slashes\ at the end are what allow you to match against the \ character

If you want to test any regexes out, there's a great site online called http://www.regextester.com/ It will allow you to play with regexes so you can test them.

Comment: Also i want to add as allowed char /, so i tried REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\\[\\\]]*"; with string str = "dsf\\sdf_[12]"; but it did not match it

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping both brackets and the minus sign :

```
String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\[\\]]*";
```

---

*Edit after your comment for "/" and "\" :*

**allow / :**

```
String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\[\\]/]*";
```

**allow \ :**

```
String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\[\\]\\\\]*";
```

**allow / and \ :**

```
String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\[\\]/\\\\]*";
```

Comment: Also i want to add as allowed char /, so i tried REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\\[\\\]]*"; with string str = "dsf\\sdf_[12]"; but it did not match it

Comment: Your comment isn't very clear, you say you want to allow / but you try with \.  
Pick what you need :  
allow / String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\[\\]/]*";  
allow \ String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\[\\]\\\\]*";  
allow / and \ String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\[\\]/\\\\]*";

Answer (score 1):

Escape also the closing brackets:

```
String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-\\[\\]]*";
```

Comment: Also i want to add as allowed char /, so i tried REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\\[\\\]]*"; with string str = "dsf\\sdf_[12]"; but it did not match it

Comment: Do you mean you want to match \ then you;ll need to escape the character twice, once for the regex, but once for the string escape as well making your regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-\\[\\]\\\\]*`

Comment: Sorry - I appear to have tried to edit your answer here - if it get's approved, feel free to remove it again ;S

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the ] in your character class as shown below:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._-\\[\\]]*
```

Comment: \\ has to be used to escape \ :)